# Show users exact causes or misusings that lead them to be banned so they can fix them

Tags: discussion, post-ban

Don't you think people need to know what they did wrong exactly so they can fix it and get unbanned from asking questions or posting answers?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I went ahead and undeleted your last five or six self-deleted posts.  All your deleted questions are almost certainly what caused the ban (because you've asked relatively few questions and a high proportion of them were deleted).  None of those questions were downvoted, but try to improve them anyway to see if you can get some upvotes and answers (answer them yourself if you can).  In the future, don't just delete old unanswered questions, try and improve them instead.  Also, check and see if undeleting these posts alone unbanned you.

Side note: I agree with the reasons we don't tell people exactly what the ban rules are, but I think self-deletion is one case where we should at least warn people that what they're doing is actively harmful.  People who are just trying to clean up seem very likely to read such a warning.  People who are just trying to game the system by deleting/re-asking are lazy sods who won't read the warning.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Bill the Lizard.This is exactly what I meant. Warning people when doing wrong. especially deleting questions. I thought that I made something good cause I didn't waste people time to read and answer them.

Answer (score 6):

The error message you get when you're question banned is:

> Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because:
>
> - Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See http://goo.gl/C1Kwu to learn more.

The answer one is similar; both link to [What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers/86998#86998), which is a pretty massive answer that explains what the user did wrong, how to fix it, and how to avoid it happening in the future

If you're looking for something that specifically says which posts caused it, it's probably the posts picking up downvotes and getting deleted, but (as that page says) the exact algorithm is secret to prevent gaming. If you're looking for something that specifically says why the posts were downvoted/deleted, an automated system can't really do that; hopefully users are leaving comments explaining what's wrong as they downvote

Comment: The problem is ex: in my case i cannot identify what's wrong in my questions, almost answered correctly, but i'm prevented from asking questions..I don't see what to do the get unbanned. In such cases I think people need help to resolve their issues.

Comment: So you're question banned? Did you remove any downvoted questions?

Comment: I deleted unanswered questions an flagged answered ones but still banned from asking questions :(. I read what the answer in that link but i think still need help to show me exactly my faults so I can fix them I think it needs to be humain-being help not straight forward advice.

Comment: On thing I can surely recommend is [to stop doing this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12062936/communicate-to-a-view-of-a-modulea-from-moduleb-in-prism). You admittedly completely changed your question to circumvent the ban. If you want to be unbanned, that is absolutely the wrong and most inappropriate approach. (I have rolled the question back to its original)

Comment: And don't delete questions. If you read the full explanation of your ban, then you will see that deleted questions factor into the ban. They more or less signal that you ask bad questions. Improve them if anything.

Comment: Thanks, good to know that. but now after being banned caused by deleting questions. how can I fix that ?

Comment: Do you think you could improve those questions? You could ask a moderator to undelete them for you. Perhaps you can then edit them back into shape. Top tip: Read the full question and answer at the link your receive which explains your ban.